# TFS Power Tools and Team Explorer 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-power-tools, team-explorer-everywhere

We have users that do not have Visual Studio installed on their computers, we need these users to be able to check files into Team Foundation Server Source Control 2015. I have read a lot about TFS Team Explorer and Power Tools but I don't know which will be better for our requirements. How do I choose which to use? One type of file that will commonly be checked in is SQL scripts. Which will be the best approach to use to enable our DBAs to check their files in?

Comment: see [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987952/without-installing-visual-studio-can-i-use-team-explorer-or-tfs-power-tools-to-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could use the Visual Studio Web Portal to manage all your source (perform checkins, checkouts). You just need to set up the permissions for these users. As nschonni said you will need to Purchase a TFS CAL for these users which is usually cheaper than buying them a copy of Visual Studio. I believe that Microsoft got rid of team explorer in order to push more users towards using the web interface which has greatly improved with each build.

This might be helpful for that method. Not sure if your using TFVC or GIT

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/work-web-portal

Answer (score 0):

There is no Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2015. You can either install the 2013 version, or Visual Studio Express https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs. Power Tools only add additional functionality on top of Team Explorer.

Either way, you'll need to purchase a TFS CAL to be able to check in code because only the MSDN versions of Visual Studio include a TFS CAL.